# minimum set of service account permission for cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I want to deploy my application on cloud run , I don't want to give my cloud run default service account as it contains high level of permissions , instead I want to create a custom service account for security purpose

so I am providing my custom service account these permission :-

1.cloud run admin

2.service account user

Is there any other permission I have to provide for my custom account in order to connect to cloud sql and use continuous deployment feature for cloud run or I am missing any other permission for the custom service account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run a Cloud Run service with a custom user-managed service account, you can use a service account with no permissions/roles. You don't need the Cloud Run Admin and the service account user. Nothing is required.

So, now, if you want to use a Cloud SQL service from your runtime identity (the custom service account), you have to grant it, at least Cloud SQL Client. Nothing more!

The Cloud Run Admin and the Service Account User roles are required on the service agent that deploys the service, not on the runtime service account itself!